# DatePicker dialog is not showing on single tap

Tags: android

**Expectation:**

When user will tap on MaterialTextView component, DatePickerDialog should open.

**Whats happening:**

User needs to tap twice on MaterialTextView component for opening DatePickerDialog.

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
MaterialTextView issueDate = findViewById(R.id.edIssueDate);
 issueDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            hideKeyboard(AddNewCoupon.this);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddNewCoupon.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    issueDate.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"/"+String.valueOf(month)+"/"+String.valueOf(year));
                    //newCustomer.hideKeyboard(AddNewCoupon.this);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

**hideKeyboard() method:**

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }

    if (imm != null)
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/edIssueDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:focusable="auto"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/txtVIssueingDtHint"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@id/edExpDate"
                        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialogForIssue"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

**Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
...

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

...
}
```

Code runs perfectly as DatePickerDialog opens but the problem is user needs to tap twice for opeining it. Where I've made mistake? How can I fix the code?

Comment: Move `hideKeyboard(AddNewCoupon.this);` to the end of block i.e. after `datePickerDialog.show();`, I think your problem is related to focus shift issue.

Comment: I ran your code and the dialog opened on one click, so the problem might be with a piece of code you haven't shared. Just FYI                        `android:onClick="showDatePickerDialogForIssue"`
is redundant as you implemented setOnClickListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **focusable** and **focusableInTouchMode** value to false, It will do the trick

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Your solutions has worked for me. Now I still have one problem. How can I manage focus-shift as when user will click on Next button the control skips this component and directly goes component which is next to DatePicker and this is bad UX. How can i manage focus shift?

Answer (score 0):

change your textview to

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/edIssueDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="@string/txtVIssueingDtHint"
                        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialogForIssue"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this option unless it is a required option.

```
android:focusable="auto"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```